# Add link title as class to wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, function, menu

I need some help with a Wordpress function that adds a link title as a class to the Wordpress menus.

So if i create a link to "about-us" i would link to add this class to the menu. Something link this:

```
<li id="menu-item-64" class="about-us menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-64">
    <a href="http://site/">about us</a>
</li>
```

I know how to do this in the Wordpress menus, but im looking for a way to do this automatically. Think i saw this on the roots theme, but im not able to reproduce this.

Hope someone can help me with this

Comment: you would need to use `Custom_walker_class` to do it. if you know how you use class with `wp_nav_menu` you can do it easily.

Comment: Oke, thanx. I will check that out.